# Mulitple pictures in one line, AsciiDoc

Tags: image, asciidoc

does anybody hase a little less hacky way to align two pictures in one line in the center?

```
[.text-center]
image:pic1.png[title="Left Center",width=300]
image:pic2.png[title="Right Center",width=300]

image::pic3.png[title="New Line and Center", width=50%,align="center"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is "hacky" about that? You have two inline images in a block, and you add a role to achieve the centering: that would be a concise solution to your question. :-)

Asciidoc markup is about expressing content with presentation hints, not about a constructing a fine-tuned layout. That said, when you coordinate your markup with custom CSS and JavaScript, you can achieve just about anything.